# Java JSyn Loopstation

Tags: java, audio, jsyn

I'm trying to program a loopstation program in JSyn inspired by something like [this](https://www.boss.info/global/products/rc-505/). The idea is, that I can record to Wav-files and play them from the program. That worked well until I attempted to do this for multiple files simultaneously. 
How do I approach this?
I cannot create multiple synthesizer engines otherwise I get an error, so I have created a class with my line out and my synthesizer. But if the audio only plays while the synthesizer sleeps, how can I play from multiple files at once?

```
System.out.println("queue the sample");
samplePlayer.dataQueue.queue(sample);
System.out.println("queued the sample");

// Wait until the sample has finished playing.
do {
    mySynth.sleepFor(1);    //synth has to sleep while sample is being played
} while (samplePlayer.dataQueue.hasMore()); //this seems to always return true -> synth never wakes up & the program crashes
```

This is adapted from the examples included in the JSyn library. I have based most of my own coding on the [JSyn Programmer's Guide](http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/docs/usersguide.php)

This is what the GUI looks like (programmed in Java Swing). It responds to the mouse and the numpad. This works.
[image: The GUI]

The constructor of my output class. This contains the synthesizer and line out.

```
public OutputMix() {
    filePath = sampleMachineFrame.filePath; //string containing path to location for sample files
    mySynth = JSyn.createSynthesizer();
    myLineOut = new LineOut();
    mySynth.add(myLineOut);
    recorder = new RecordMic[10]; //one recorder for each button (my own class)
    player = new PlayFromWav[10]; //one player for each button (my own class)
}
```

The **recording works** absolutely fine. I can even start overlapping recordings (i.e. record to two files at once) and play them with an external program. 
But when I try to **play** them back the **synthesizer never wakes up** and I am also struggling to imagine **how I would play multiple files at once**.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you do not want to sleep in your program unless you are sequencing events. Just queue samples in response to Button events and let them run.

If the files are small enough then you can just load them into memory. Then you can queue multiple files any time you want. You might need to increase the heap size of your Java virtual machine.

Here is an example: https://github.com/philburk/jsyn/blob/master/tests/com/jsyn/examples/PlaySample.java

If the samples are too big then you will have to stream them off the disk using multiple threads, which is more difficult.

You can make all the samples the same size. Then they will stay in phase. Or you can trigger them at specific beats using timestamps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I have rethought my approach. Now I would like to use blank float samples(all the same size), that can be modified by recording to them. Is it possible to record to the float samples directly or do I have to write them as files?

Comment: You can record to a FloatSample very easily by queuing them to a  FixedRateMonoWriter or a FixedRateStereoWriter. You have to start() the writer.

https://github.com/philburk/jsyn/blob/master/src/com/jsyn/unitgen/FixedRateMonoWriter.java

Comment: Thank you, this works great. Is it also possible to do this for a sample without a fixed size? My idea was, that I would determine the size of the samples by the size of the first one. However it seems there is only a constructor for mono samples with unlimited size, not for stereo samples. How can I record a stereo sample without a fixed size?

Comment: Correction: There are no constructors for float samples of an unlimited size, neither for mono nor stereo.